# SARSA with Linear Function Approximation weight overflow

Tags: python, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm trying to solve the [CartPole](https://gym.openai.com/envs/CartPole-v1/) problem, implemented in OpenAI Gym.
In each state the agent is able to perform one of 2 actions move left or right.
The reward is always +1. The epsiode ends after 500 steps or when the pole falls over. The state consists of 4 values the cart's position, velocity, the pole angle
and the angleRate (I'm not quite sure what the last one means).
I've omitted the position because it makes no difference where the cart is except for some rare edge cases, when the cart would go out of bounds.

I tried to solve this problem by approximating the state action value $Q(s,a)$ with SARSA and a linear function for each action. The problem is that the algorithm is able to learn how to balance the pole for 500 steps but then it jumps back to around 100. It proceeds to cycle while the weights start to grow rapidly until they overflow.

[image] [image]

The state contains no information about the amount of steps until the episode ends and maybe because of that it starts to approximate an infinite reward. But even with the time included the weights overflow.
I've also tried to use the [sklearn LinearRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) to check if my regression implementation is wrong. The Regressor didn't overflow but it did not even come close to a reward of 500.
The last thing I tried was to use combined states like $positon * velocity$ and $velocity * pole angle$ etc. But that didn't fix the overflowing it just helped to reach the reward of 500 more often.

So I'm out of ideas why my weights keeps overflowing. Below is a shorter but working version of my code. I do not think that there is a problem with my code but it seems like I'm doing something fundamentaly wrong.

```
import random as rand
import numpy as np
import gym
import sys

class SemiGradientSarsaAgent:

    def __init__(self, stateSize, actions, explorationRate, stepSize, rewardDiscount):
        self.actions = np.array(actions)
        self.weights = np.zeros((len(actions), stateSize), dtype=np.float32)
        self.explorationRate = explorationRate
        self.stepSize = stepSize
        self.rewardDiscount = rewardDiscount

    def chooseAction(self, state):
        return self.__chooseActionInternal__(state)[1]

    def learn(self, state, action, newState, reward, done):
        prevQValue = self.__getQValue__(state, action)
        if done:
            step = self.stepSize * (reward - prevQValue)
        else:
            nextQValue = self.__chooseActionInternal__(newState)[0]
            step = self.stepSize * (reward + self.rewardDiscount * nextQValue - prevQValue)

        # Gradient descent: The Gradient for the weights is the state itself
        gradient = state
        self.weights[action] += step * gradient

    def __chooseActionInternal__(self, state):
        # Epsilon Greedy
        qValues = np.array([self.__getQValue__(state, action) for action in self.actions])
        if rand.random() < self.explorationRate:
            index = rand.choice(range(len(self.actions)))
        else:
            index = np.argmax(qValues)

        return (qValues[index], self.actions[index])

    # Calculate the QValue with a linear function
    def __getQValue__(self, state, action):
        return np.sum(state * self.weights[action])

def trainAgent(agent, episodes = 1):
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
    totalRewards = []
    for i in range(episodes):
        sys.stdout.write("\rEpisode {}\\{}".format(i + 1, episodes))
        state = env.reset()
        # throw out the position
        state = np.array([*state[1:]]) 
        totalReward = 0
        # Run one episode and train the agent
        while True:
            action = agent.chooseAction(state)
            newState, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            # throw out the position
            newState = np.array([*newState[1:]]) 

            totalReward += reward
            agent.learn(state, action, newState, reward, done)

            if done:
                break

            state = newState

        totalRewards.append(totalReward)

    return totalRewards

agent = SemiGradientSarsaAgent(3, np.array([0, 1]), 0.1, 0.8, 1)
rewards = trainAgent(agent, 3000)
```

Comment: I don't know much about SARSA or RL generally (just started reading) but on its face it seems like these kinds of wild oscillations might be controlled with some manner of regularization. Have you looked into that?

Comment: No I haven't tried to use regularization, you mean something like lasso regression?

Comment: The kind of regularization I have in mind is not unlike lasso -- I'm thinking of applying a penalty to the L1 or L2 norm of the weights in the network, or enforcing a maximum norm on the weights.

Comment: @Sycorax So I've tried to use L2 regularization so my weight update would look like this $w_{t+1} = w_t - 0.5  \alpha  \nabla_{w_t}[(v_\pi - \sum w_t x)^2  + \lambda\sum w_t^2 ] = (1-\alpha\lambda)w_t + \alpha(v_\pi-\hat{v_\pi})x$ where $x$ are my features and $v_\pi$ is the function that I'm trying to approximate by using SARSA which means $v_\pi \approx reward + \hat{v_\pi}$. It stops my algorithm from overflowing the weights but now I'm not able to reach a reward of 500 (I've tried different values for $\lambda$ but none worked. Sometimes the algorithm even starts overflowing again...